# Disable add more file inputs if the first it's empty, javascript

Tags: javascript, json, html

I'm working on a project that has the option to add attached files, you can add as many as you want, but I want to disable add more inputs if the first it's empty, the third if the second it's empty and so on...

HTML CODE:

```
<input type="hidden" name="file_count" value="1" id="file_count">
<div id="file_block">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="p-in" class="col-md-4 label-heading" style="margin-top:0px"><?php echo lang("ctn_438") ?></label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <input type="file" name="user_file_1" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="button" name="s" value="<?php echo lang("ctn_439") ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" onclick="add_file()">
```

Javascript

```
function add_file() 
{
    var count = $('#file_count').val();
    count++;
    var html = '<div class="form-group">'+
                    '<label for="p-in" class="col-md-4 label-heading"><?php echo lang("ctn_438") ?></label>'+
                    '<div class="col-md-8">'+
                        '<input type="file" name="user_file_'+count+'" class="form-control">'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>';
    $('#file_block').append(html);
    $('#file_count').val(count);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: So add a check to see if the field has a value before adding? Or onchange of the field, enable/disable the button?

Comment: do you have an example? im trying this:
<script>
(function() {
    $('form > input').keyup(function() {

        var empty = false;
        $('form > input').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                empty = true;
            }
        });

        if (empty) {
            $('#boton').attr("style", "display:none");
        } else {
            $('#boton').removeAttr("style", "display:none");
        }
    });
})()
</script>
not working at all

Comment: why use keyup? Use `change`